Videos and their relation to the Prohibition of Imagery
Praise be to Allah,
Assalamu alaykyum,
Hello, my question is simple. It is well known that in Sahih Bukhari, imagery is forbidden. However, how does this apply to videos which are images (called frames) (created with pixels, and therefore I could argue that they are 'drawn') that are simply in the thousands and move like in a slideshow (but extremely fast)?
I am aware that other scholars have already ruled that videos are different than pictures, however I find their reasoning to be often forget that videos are images, there are simply thousands of them.
I have been avoiding youtube and all videos for a while, due to a hadith which states that the Prophet salla allahu allayhee wa salem (pbuh) stated that,

''What is lawful is clear and what is unlawful is clear, but between them are certain doubtful things which many people do not know. So he who guards against doubtful things keeps his religion and his honour blameless. But he who falls into doubtful things falls into that which is unlawful, just as a shepherd who grazes his cattle in the vicinity of a pasture declared prohibited (by the king); he is likely to stray into the pasture. Mind you, every king has a protected pasture and Allah's involved limits is that which He has declared unlawful. Verily, there is a piece of flesh in the body, if it is healthy, the whole body is healthy, and if it is corrupt, the whole body is corrupt. Verily, it is the heart''

This hadith is the reason why I have blocked videos from my life regardless of other scholars ruling they are okay because they seem to be a middle position which is best to avoid.
Is my reasoning sound?
Or could it be argued that instead, I am actually forbidding something lawful? Which is itself a sin stated in the quran? ex:

Do not forbid the good things which Allah has made lawful for you, and do not transgress (Surah Al-Ma'idah - 87-88)

In general, are videos prohibited? Is the consensus on whether they are or are not unanimous? (like does everyone say its okay, or only some do) and is my reasoning sound to avoid them?
For all who might answer, may you tell me before answering if you are an expert or simply a fellow Muslim giving his opinion? Thank you.
